A more intuitive argument to maximize $u^T \sqrt{X} (\sqrt{X} P \sqrt{X} + I)^{-1} \sqrt{X} u$.
$\newcommand{\hX}{\sqrt{X}}$Let $P$ be a real, symmetric positive semidefinite matrix, and let $u$ denote a unit vector. Let $\mathcal{X}$ denote the space of real positive semidefinite matrices with unit trace.
Consider the function
$$
f(X) = u^T\hX(\hX P \hX + I)^{-1} \hX u
$$
Here $\hX$ denotes the positive semidefinite square root of $X$. It can be shown (see below) that
$$
\sup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} f(X) = u^T (P+I)^{-1} u \quad \mbox{with} \quad \text{arg max}_{X \in \mathcal{X}} f(X) \ni \frac{(P + I)^{-1} u u^T (P + I)^{-1}}{u^T (P+I)^{-2} u}
$$
Question: Is there a more intuitive / alternative proof of these facts than the one I provide below?
My Proof: To begin with, note that by continuity we have
$$
f(X) = \lim_{\tau \to 0^{+}}  u^T(P + X_\tau^{-1})^{-1} u \quad \mbox{where}~X_\tau = X + \tau I. 
$$
As $X \in \mathcal{X}$, we have $X_\tau \preceq (1+\tau) I$. Thus,
$$
f(X) \leq \lim_{\tau \to 0^+} u^T(P + (1+\tau)^{-1} I)^{-1} u = u^T (P + I)^{-1} u.
$$
On the other hand, consider a unit vector $v$. Then by the Sherman-Morrison formula, we have
$$
\sup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} f(X) \geq \sup_{\|v\|_2 = 1} f(vv^T) = \sup_{\|v\|_2= 1}\frac{(u^T v)^2}{v^T(P+I) v} = u^T(P+I)^{-1}u.
$$
Moreover, this is attained with $v \propto (P+I)^{-1} u$.
One idea I was trying to make work was to note that $\sqrt{X}(\sqrt{X} P \sqrt{X} + I)^{-1} \sqrt{X}$ almost looks like a Schur complement.

This is puzzling: $f$ is concave, not convex, but the maximiser occurs at the boundary.

Yeah, $f$ is concave in $X$.

I have not found any intuitive proof, but I have found a way to explain why some rank-one orthogonal projection must optimise $f$.
Suppose for the moment that $P$ is positive definite. Let $A=P^{1/2}X^{1/2}$. Using the identity $A(BA+I)^{-1}B=I-(AB+I)^{-1}$, we have
\begin{align}
f(X)
&=u^TP^{-1/2}A(A^TA+I)^{-1}A^TP^{-1/2}u\\
&=u^TP^{-1/2}\left[I - (AA^T+I)^{-1} \right]P^{-1/2}u\\
&=u^TP^{-1/2}\left[I - (P^{1/2}XP^{1/2}+I)^{-1} \right]P^{-1/2}u\\
&=u^TP^{-1}u - u^TP^{-1}(X+P^{-1})^{-1}P^{-1}u.\tag{1}\\
\end{align}
Therefore $f$ is concave in $X$.
Although $I\not\in\mathcal X$ (except in the scalar case), $f(I)$ is an upper bound of $f(X)$ for all $X\in\mathcal X$. Since $I$ is bounded away from $\mathcal X$, at first I had the impression that this upper bound must be loose. However, by $(1)$,
\begin{align*}
f(X)-f(I)
&=u^TP^{-1}\left[(X+P^{-1})^{-1}-(I+P^{-1})^{-1}\right]P^{-1}u\\
&=u^TP^{-1} (X+P^{-1})^{-1}\left[(I+P^{-1})-(X+P^{-1})\right](I+P^{-1})^{-1}P^{-1}u\\
&=u^TP^{-1} (X+P^{-1})^{-1}(I-X)(I+P^{-1})^{-1}P^{-1}u\\
&=u^TP^{-1} (X+P^{-1})^{-1}(I-X)(P+I)^{-1}u.\\
\end{align*}
Therefore, if $X$ is the rank-one orthogonal projection onto the linear span of $(P+I)^{-1}u$, that is, if we take $X=\Pi_{P,u}:=\frac{(P+I)^{-1}uu^T(P+I)^{-1}}{u^T(P+I)^{-2}u}$, we will have $(I-X)(P+I)^{-1}u=0$ and in turn $f(X)=f(I)$. Hence $\Pi_{P,u}$ is a global optimiser of $f$.
Now suppose that $P$ is positive semidefinite. To emphasise the dependence of $f$ on $P$, let us write $f_P$ instead of $f$. Let $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of positive definite matrices convergent to $P$. Then
$$
f_P(X)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{P_n}(X)
\le\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{P_n}(\Pi_{P_n,u})
=f_P(\Pi_{P,u}).
$$
Therefore $\Pi_{P,u}$ is still a global optimiser of $f_P$, regardless of the invertibility of $P$.
